# Скрипт теоремы Пифагора

Tags: php

```
<?php
define('КАТЕТ1','a');
define('КАТЕТ2','b');
define('ГИПОТЕНУЗА','c');
$umnogenie1=a*a;
$umnogenie2=b*b;
$umnogenie3=c*c;
$slogenie=$umnogenie1+$umnogenie2;
$slogenie=$umnogenie3;
echo"$slogenie=$umnogenie3";
?>
```

Должно получиться на сервере `a^2+b^2=c^2`, а выходит `0=0`. Что я делаю не так? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Какой-то бредовый код, почему названия констант на кириллице?

Что за "a*a" ? Вы умножаете символы?

Или я что-то не понял?

Comment: код жесткий, ах, +1

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['katet'] && $_POST['katet2'] && $_POST['gipot']))
{
$k1 = $_POST['katet'];
$k2 = $_POST['katet2'];
$g = $_POST['gipot'];
$r = $k1*$k1+$k2*$k2 ." = ". $g*$g;
echo $r;
}
?>
<form action="index.php method="POST">
<input type="number" name="katet">
<input type="number" name="katet2">
<input type="number" name="gipot">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = 3;
$b = 4;
$c = 5;

echo $a*$a+$b*$b ." = ". $c*$c;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Geometry
{

    /**
     * @param array $cathetus
     * @param bool|integer $hypothenuse
     * @return bool|string
     */
    public static function pifagorTheorem($cathetus = [], $hypothenuse = false)
    {
        if (count($cathetus) != 2 || !$hypothenuse) {
            return 'No result';
        }

        return strval((pow($cathetus[0], 2) + pow($cathetus[1], 2)) == pow($hypothenuse, 2));
    }
}

echo Geometry::pifagorTheorem([3, 4], 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function pythagoras($a,$b,$c,$precision=4)
{
    ($a) ? $a = pow($a,2) : $find .= 'a';
    ($b) ? $b = pow($b,2) : $find .= 'b';
    ($c) ? $c = pow($c,2) : $find .= 'c';

    switch ($find)
    {
        case 'a':
            return round(sqrt($c - $b),$precision);
        break;
        case 'b':
            return round(sqrt($c - $a),$precision);
        break;
        case 'c':
            return round(sqrt($a + $b),$precision);
        break;
    }

    return false;
}

/*
echo pythagoras(5,false,13); // 12
*/
```